# Makefile: add directory and modify extenstion in path

Tags: makefile

I have a variable (which typically reflects the target's name) in one of the following two forms (with and without extension)

```
BUILD_DIR/DIR1/DIR2/DIR3/A
BUILD_DIR/DIR1/DIR2/DIR3/B.ext
```

For a give variable I would like to add another layer (`DIR0`) under `BUILD_DIR` and add/change `.ext` to `.new_ext`.

So that the variables above are both transformed into

```
BUILD_DIR/DIR0/DIR1/DIR2/DIR3/A.new_ext
BUILD_DIR/DIR0/DIR1/DIR2/DIR3/B.new_ext
```

In other words `DIR0` is added right after `BUILD_DIR` and extension is changed if it was present and added if not.

Having a function in the `Makefile` that does the job should also be sufficient.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Isn't this simply a case of using a combination of `patsubst` and `addsuffix` calls (assuming you're using gnu make)?

Comment: I tried to use `patsubst` without too much success so far.
`$(patsubst %/,%/DIR0/,$@)` or `$(@:%/,%/DIR0/)`. Where `$@` contains the value I want to modify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that seems to be the shortest among presented so far

```
FUNC = $(patsubst $(2)/%,$(2)/$(DIR0)/%.new_ext,$(1:%.ext=%))

$(call FUNC,$(VARIABLE),$(BUILD_DIR))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the paths are in a variable such as...

```
PATHS := BUILD_DIR/DIR1/DIR2/DIR3/A BUILD_DIR/DIR1/DIR2/DIR3/B.ext
```

Then try something like...

```
EXTRA_DIR     := DIR0
NEW_EXTENSION := new_ext

PATHS := $(addsuffix .$(NEW_EXTENSION),$(patsubst %.ext,%,$(patsubst BUILD_DIR/%,BUILD_DIR/$(EXTRA_DIR)/%,$(PATHS))))
```